# Why can't we delete an initialized pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I am initializing a `char` pointer with some random values, and when I am trying to delete it, I am unable to. Why is that?

Here is what I am doing:

```
int main()
{
    char *s = new char[50];    /* 
                                * I know there is no reason for 
                                * using new if initializing, but 
                                * in order to use delete we need 
                                * to allocate using new.
                                */
    s = "Harry";
    delete s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you need to use `delete []` and not just `delete` whenever you're deleting an array and not a single object. That is not the only issue with your code, though.

Comment: What everybody forgot to mention is that `char* = "Harry";` is not a valid expression in the first place and a compiler conforming to the current standard (C++11) should reject it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you really want to practice with pointer, you need to fix your code. The main problem is you are trying to assign string literal( which is **const char[6]** in here) to pointer `s` then try to modify it by calling delete which invoke undefined behavior(`UB`).

```
char *s = new char[50];    
strcpy(s, "Harry");     // don't assign string literal to it
                        // re-assign pointer to string literal,
                        // lost pre-allocated memory position and caused delete to fail 
                        // it's UB to modify string literal
delete []s;             // new[]/delete[], new/delete need to be called in pair.
```

Just use `std::string` instead.

```
#include <string>
std::string s("Harry"); // no worries
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that after this assignment:

```
s = "Harry";
```

Then your `s` is no longer pointing to the memory you have allocated. It is pointing to *a different* array, or a `const char[6]` to be precise. The other array isn't dynamically allocated, and isn't on the heap. You can't `delete` variables that aren't on the heap.

In addition, by changing the `s` pointer to point at something else before the dynamically allocated memory has been freed, you introduce a memory leak.

To fix your code, either copy `"Harry"` into the `s` array by using `strcpy`, or use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You should **never initialize** a pointer with a string constant this way. It creates **memory leaks** which can be very dangerous.
When you allocated the memory using new, a 50 char memory was allocated in heap and its pointer is returned in s. when you were trying to initializing this value (wrong way) using `s="Harry`" , a new space is allocated in stack, initialized with this value and returned in s.

This memory allocated in stack cannot be deleted using `delete` call  because it works only on heap.
Also, the memory initially allocated using new can no longer be accessed using s. Thus, you have a memory leak over here.

You can notice a different address in your pointer `s` after this wrong initialization by making small changes in your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char *s = new char[50];    
        printf("\n %u",s);  // print address before init
        s = "Harry";
        printf("\n %u",s);  // print address after init
//      delete s;           // cannot delete from stack
        return 0;
}
```

Like others have already suggested, an array of character should be initialized using

```
strcpy(s, "Harry");
```

Answer (score 3):

A char* is not actually a string. It is a pointer to some character with more characters to follow and ending with '\0'.

A character literal in C (and thus in C++) like "abc" is just an array of characters, with the compiler silently adding a '\0'. When you assign an array to a pointer, the array silently converts a pointer to the first element. 
s = "Harry" means, the pointer s is assigned the address of the first character in the string literal "Harry". So the old value is lost and as this was the address of a dynamically allocated character array, leakage is supposed to happen.

std::strcpy, on the other hand, copies a string character by character from one array to another array. No pointers will be changed, only pieces of memory are copied. The pointer to the target array still points to the target array afterwards, only the data in that array has changed.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this occurs with initialized pointers.

When using a pointer, you can only delete (free) the memory it's pointing to, not the pointer itself, since it's an automatic object and will be deleted at the end of the block.